# bug with my ansible playbook "when" condition

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have the following plays:

```
  - name: packagexx version check
    shell: apk version packagexx | awk 'NR>1{$1=$1;print}'
    when: "'web' in group_names"
    register: packxx_apk_version
    changed_when: False  
  - debug: msg="package_version_check {{inventory_hostname}} {{packxx_apk_version.stdout}}"
    when: "'web' in group_names"
  - name: packagexx individual files check
    shell: apk audit /etc/packagexx/ | grep "^U" | grep -v "kamcc"
    when : "'web' in group_names and '=' in packxx_apk_version.stdout"
    register: ind_file_apk_version
    failed_when: False  
    changed_when: False
  - debug: msg="individual_files_check {{inventory_hostname}} packagexx {{ind_file_apk_version.stdout}}"
    when: "'web' in group_names"
```

The second play is only supposed to run when the output from the first play includes an "=" sign. 
BUt right now, it runs when the output looks like this:

```
  test-web:~# apk version packagexx
  Installed:                                Available:
  packagexx-1.2.0-r3                        < 1.2.1-r1
```

And ultimately, I end up with this error when the playbook runs:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
fatal: [test-web]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'"}
fatal: [test2-web]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'"}
```

And that makes sense because the command in the second play is not supposed to return anything in cases where the package is out of date.

I can't see where my bug is.  Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1**

So on more testing, here's what I found.
When I run this playbook on a server that does have an up to date package (aka it has "=" in the output) it runs just fine. 
When I run it on a box where the package is outdated (no "=" in the output), it returns the error.

The bug / missing piece was the condition of the last debug statement.  It too needs to check for "=".  At least that's what I've done and it seems to work.

So this:

```
  - debug: msg="individual_files_check {{inventory_hostname}} packagexx {{ind_file_apk_version.stdout}}"
    when: "'web' in group_names"
```

was changed to :

```
  - debug: msg="individual_files_check {{inventory_hostname}} packagexx {{ind_file_apk_version.stdout}}"
    when: "'web' in group_names and '=' in packxx_apk_version.stdout"
```

Comment: It looks like your *debug* task is failing, which happens *before* the task with failing `when` condition?  Also, what if you print out the value of `packxx_apk_version` rather than `packxx_apk_version.stdout`?

Comment: yeah so i'm going to try to just print the variable name, vs. variablename + "stdout"

Comment: also, you don't need `'web' in group_names`. Just use `- hosts: web`

Comment: @shaps, actually, i do need it.  because this playbook runs on multiple types of hosts.  to keep things simple, i just showed you two plays within a bigger playbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add a condition to the debug statement to only print when the output exists, like so:

```
- debug: msg="individual_files_check {{inventory_hostname}} packagexx {{ind_file_apk_version.stdout}}"
    when: "'web' in group_names and '=' in packxx_apk_version.stdout"
```